# Could not fetch && merge to my local master branch

Tags: git

```
$ git fetch origin master
From https://github.com/haolly/UGUI_learn
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

$ git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

$ git merge master
Already up to date.
```

I do not want to use git pull, so I use fetch/merge, but I can't merge the upstream   to my local branch, as you can see, there are 2 commits I need to merge

Comment: "*I do not want to use git pull*". Why? That's how you get the latest changes...

Comment: @ObsidianAge  because git pull = git fetch + git merge, I like to do it manually

Comment: What version of Git are you using? Did you create this clone as a single-branch clone, and if so, with what branch names? (If you're using Git 1.7, you must not add `master` to your `git fetch` command: this suppresses the update of `origin/master`. This is fixed since Git 1.8.2.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you don't want to use "git pull".  But you probably want:

```
git merge origin/master
```

git merge master (when on the master branch) will attempt to merge your local master branch with itself

Answer (score 2):

To merge with any updates that are in `origin/master`, run:

```
git merge origin/master
```

If `origin/master` is set as the upstream of `master`, and you are on `master`, you can run:

```
git merge
```

with no arguments at all.

(As noted in commits above, be sure your Git is at least version 1.8.2.)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: it hadn't been while I was typing and clicked the post button :-) I was just a little slower than the other answer.